# dealing with different numeric formats within the same file in R

Tags: r, data.table, format, radix

I am using a file that relies on user input. Of course this input is inconsistent and I am not sure what the best way to deal with this? I am working with numbers, which are I have read in as character:

```
mydata$output1
    [1] "PP150" NA "50,376.45\r\n" "40096.21" "43721.59" NA NA "27282272.16" NA
```

`"50,376.45\r\n"`  actually shows up as a simple number in the preview, i have (in my limited experience) never seen anything similiar. How can i create a numeric vector out of this?

I want to get:

```
[1] "PP150" NA "50376.45" "40096.21" "43721.59" NA NA "27282272.16" NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove characters that you don't want :

```
x <- c("PP150",NA, "50,376.45\r\n","40096.21","43721.59",NA,NA,"27282272.16", NA)

gsub('[,\r\n]', '', x)
#[1] "PP150"   NA  "50376.45" "40096.21" "43721.59"  NA  NA   "27282272.16" NA
```

The final output would still be a string since "PP150" is not a number.